# Python data encryption

Tags: python, cryptography

I have  the task to hide customer's data form my script. I am using this [example](https://github.com/nikodraca/PostTrends/blob/master/app.py). I don't understand the

```
import creds
import sys
import calendar

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = creds.ACCESS_TOKEN
```

How we create `creds` file? Are there any examples of this?

Comment: The file is called creds.pyc. You may want to read the python documentation on that. From what I can tell, this is an encrypted file.

Comment: Simple google search provided [this](https://pypi.org/project/creds/)

Comment: @Dux -- After taking a look, I don't think that's what's being used here.  It looks to me like creds is a user-created python file, compiled to a .pyc file, and residing in the same directory as the original python source.  It would simply assign a global ACCESS_TOKEN.  It's just a way to pass the token in.  To create the .pyc file just run the .py file in python.

Comment: @JeffLearman you might be right...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately after looking at the link you added, it seems like you have taken something out of the middle of a script. I would recommend reading the information about how the module cred's actually works rather than hi-jacking it. You will be a lot better off if you understand the concept behind what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Create `creds.py` in the same directory, with contents like this:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN = "myaccesstoken..."
```

Check syntax by running it:

```
python3 creds.py
```

It will be importable into your original source.

However, I doubt whether this is a good pattern for security.  All it does is separate the access token from your main source file by "hiding" it in another source file.  Hopefully someone with a strong background in security will pipe up with a better pattern.  It's the kind of thing that is very easy to "make work" but "get wrong".

This might be a case where simple is OK, though, assuming that the creds are *your* creds and not a customer's creds, and the platform you're running the python code on is secure.

Comment: I think I have quite a lot of background, but in the end it depends on the system and the system configuration, the use case and threat models. But to make it easier: *access to the key should be minimalized*. And yes, storing it in source can be more secure than storing it in a config file or DB or similar, **if** access to the core requires more credentials / frequent authentication / access to different systems etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes -- That makes sense, and implies that the reason for separating the key as done here is to simplify key administration rather than improve security.  It's still a good reason: no need to revise source when simply updating keys.